# a ideal of the ring of regular functions of an affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We assume that $\Bbb k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Let $X \subset \Bbb A^n$ be an affine $\Bbb k$-variety  , let's consider $ \mathfrak A_X \subset \Bbb k[t_1,...t_n]$ as the ideal of polynomials that vanish on $X$. Given a closed subset $Y\subset X$ we associate the ideal $ a_Y \subset k[X]$ defined by $
a_Y  = \left\{ {f \in k[X];f = 0\,on\,Y} \right\}
$. 
I'm reading " Basic Algebraic Geometry of Shafarevich" and it says that " It follows from Nullstellensatz that $Y$ is the empty set if and only if $a_Y = K[X] $ But I don't know how to prove this . Maybe it's trivial , but I need help anyway.

After knowing if the result is true here, I want to know if it's true in the case of quasiprojective varieties, but first the affine case =)

It remains to prove that if $ Y\subset X $ then $$
Y = \phi  \Rightarrow a_Y  = k\left[ X \right]
$$
For that side we need Hilbert Nullstelensatz, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I have replaced your  $U_X$ by $\mathfrak A_X$, the letter that  Shafarevich actually uses: it is a Gothic A ( *Fraktur A* in German).I have also corrected the spelling of *Nullstellensatz*.

Comment: I'm not sure why the Nullstellensatz is necessary here. If every function vanishes on a set $Y$ (including all constant functions) then the set $Y$ must obviously be empty; else the function $f(x) = 1$ would be non-vanishing at some point $x$. Conversely if the set $Y$ is empty then every function attains 0 at every point of $Y$.

Comment: Yes... I'm not sure why they need Nullstelensatz :/!

Comment: You are absolutely right @User 24601, the Nullstellensatz is completely irrelevant here: +1. It is reassuring for us mere mortals that even Shafarevich could make such an egregious mistake!

Comment: Dear Daniel, you call your base field $k, \mathbb k$ and $K$. Please, make up your mind!

Comment: Also, User 24601's reasoning  is valid for quasi-projective varieties too.

Comment: Okay. I'll just put it as an answer below so we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The Nullstellensatz is unnecessary here. If every function vanishes on a set Y (including all constant functions) then the set Y must obviously be empty; else the function f(x)=1 would be non-vanishing at some point x. Conversely if the set Y is empty then every function attains 0 at every point of Y.

Comment: We want to prove the following: $$
Y = \phi  \Leftrightarrow a_Y  = k\left[ X \right]
$$
We proved one side of the equality , more specifically $
\left(  \Leftarrow  \right)
$ proving the contrapositive. For the other side we probably need Nullstelensatz, in fact this is more general than Nullstelensatz, to see this only consider $ Y\subset X $ but $X=\Bbb A^n$ , then $ k[X]=k[t_1,...,t_n]=k[T] $ , and in this case $ a_Y = I(Y) $ (the polynomials that vanish on Y ) thus $
Y = \phi  \Leftrightarrow a_Y  = I\left( Y \right) = k\left[ X \right] = k\left[ T \right]
$
which is precisely hilbert

Comment: Daniel, this is not more general than the Nullstellensatz. And both implications have been proven in the answer above. If $I(Y) = k[X]$, then every function vanishes on $Y$ -- including the function that attains the value $1$ at every point, for instance. (This corresponds to the unit element of $k[X]$.) Now, what does this say about $Y$? Remember that many logical statements are *vacuously true* for the empty set.